# How to set Style on object created in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, scichart

I have some xaml code like this:

```
<s:SciChartSurface>
    <s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
        <s:NumericAxis Style="{Binding ..., Converter=...}" />
    </s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
</s:SciChartSurface>
```

The x axis has a style that depends on a property. The converter selectes one of three different static resources defined somewhere in the xaml.
Now the axis itself is polymorph, too, so I create it in the code behind:

```
<s:SciChartSurface>
    <s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
        <Binding CreateAxis />
    </s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
</s:SciChartSurface>
```

or

```
<s:SciChartSurface XAxis="{Binding CreateAxis}" />
```

But how can I apply the dynamic style to the object created in the code behind?

Comment: so why is that a downvote? I spent a whole day trying to get this working and searching for an answer before I asked. It just took me some time to verify the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear since you haven't posted any code-behind code at all, but I believe you want to be able to do something like this:

```
var axis = new SciChart.Charting.Visuals.Axes.NumericAxis();
axis.SetBinding(SciChart.Charting.Visuals.Axes.NumericAxis.StyleProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Path") { Converter = new YourConverterClass });
ss.XAxis = axis;
```

Give the `SciChartSurface` element an `x:Name` in your XAML markup and then set its `XAxis` property to a `NumericAxis` object that you create programmatically:

```
<s:SciChartSurface x:Name="ss">
```

Comment: not exactly. instead of the 2nd line I want to say axis.Style = ..., the ... would then replace the converter (a converter is a hack around limitations of xaml), the 3rd line would still be in the xaml. the link to the similar problem shows that I can easily access the styles defined in the xaml

Comment: Where is your actual style defined then? Because you are *binding* the Style property to a source property in the sample XAML you have posted.